# He intentado crear varios arrays para cargar diferentes elementos pero no hay manera

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, dart

No se como crear el array de imágenes en un widget reutilizable ni implementarlo en la clase. Es para que en cada Card se vea una imagen distinta. Y lo mismo con el título, descripción y 2 botones de ButtonBar, todo dentro de la Card me refiero. Es muy lioso para mi. Lo he intentado pero no hay manera.
Necesito ayuda con esto. Gracias.

Comment: explica un poco más sobre que es lo que deseas hacer

Comment: Muestra un [repro] de lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

primero que todo te recomendaría entregar un poco mas de información acerca de la duda que tengas. Por lo que se entiende, deberias de construir un array de mapas para asi procesarlo en un for in, de esta forma podria hacer lo de a continuacion. espero te sirva.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final imagenes = [];
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView(
    children: [
      for (var imagen in imagenes) 
        llamarImagenes(imagen),
    ],
  ),
);
}

Widget llamarImagenes(imagen) {
  return Card(
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text(imagen.titulo),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Image(image: imagen.url),
        ),
        Text(imagen.descripcion),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```